# Interactive Brokers TWS API - How can I get orders, which is not submitted yet?

Tags: python, tws

I have this script which print placed orders. But how I can get orders which is not submitted yet? [image: This is an example of such order. The button 'T' did't clicked yet.]

I use reqAllOpenOrders() method, but it returned only submitted orders.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time
import requests

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('Open Order: simbol-{:s} secType-{:s}. Type: orderType-{:s} action-{:s} at trailStopPrice-{:f}'.
              format(contract.symbol, contract.secType, order.orderType, order.action, order.trailStopPrice ))
def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server
app.reqAllOpenOrders()
time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data

app.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Orders that are not transmitted are not considered 'active'.
They will not appear in the callbacks

[From https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_submission.html](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_submission.html)

> An order can be sent to TWS but not transmitted to the IB server by
> setting the IBApi.Order.Transmit flag in the order class to False.
> Untransmitted orders will only be available within that TWS session
> (not for other usernames) and will be cleared on restart. Also, they
> can be cancelled or transmitted from the API **but not viewed while they
> remain in the "untransmitted" state**.

Note "...not viewed..."

Also there are other reasons such as precautionary settings in TWS that can prevent orders being transmitted.

Also see https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topic/36816324 for further info.

> The issue is that non-transmitted orders do not flow through
> openOrder or completedOrder so I can visually see that the order has
> been placed on TWS but I cannot confirm it through the api.

If the api app had placed the order then it has the orderId to modify or cancel that order, otherwise it will not be informed via the api callbacks about the order.